# List of components not updating

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I have this template displaying a list of components:

```
<template>
  <v-container id="container">
    <RaceItem v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item + index" />
  (...)
```

When the array "items" is updated (shift() or push() a new item), the list displayed is not updated.
I'm sure I'm missing something on how Vue works... but could anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: use index only as key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) attribute expects `number | string | boolean | symbol`. It is recommended to use primitives as keys.

The simplest usage is to use a primitive unique property of each element to track them:

```
 <RaceItem v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" />
```

... assuming your `items` have unique `id`s.

---

If you use the `index` as key, every time you update the array you'll have to replace it with an updated version of itself (i.e: `this.items = [...items];` - where `items` contains the mutation).

Here's how your methods would have to look in that case:

```
methods: {
  applyChangeToItem(item, change) {
    // apply change to item and return the modified item
  },
  updateItem(index, change) {
    this.$set(
      this.items, 
      index, 
      this.applyChangeToItem(this.items[index], change)
    );
  },
  addItem(item) {
    this.items = [...this.items, item];
  },
  removeItem(index) {
    this.items = [...this.items.filter((_, i) => index !== i)];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've changed the :key and I'm using now only the "index" but I'm facing another weird behavior. I want the "removeItem" method to always remove the first item : this.items = [...this.items.filter((_, i) => i !== 0)]; But it always remove the last one... I'm still investigating why.

Comment: @kururin, use codesanbox.io (or a [so] snippet) to create a [mcve] and i'll take a look.

Comment: Here is an example: https://codepen.io/kururin/pen/WNwwgpo?editors=1111
I'm sure it's something stupid... but I can't get it.

Comment: The problem (I think) was the index. It works that way:
https://codepen.io/kururin/pen/rNeeqqB?editors=1010

Comment: @kururin, from Vue's point of view, all your `items` are identical (they have a value of `'race-item'`). Their random number assigned in the template is a side effect and not tracked. Vue is correctly removing the first, but doesn't have a unique identifier to keep track of (and update) each one's template (because their references are equal: the `'race-item'` string. As I said, you need a unique identifier. Simplest way would be to assign their random values when you create them: https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/RwaadMY. Now Vue will correctly keep track of each one.

Comment: You'll also notice now the local random values are correctly tracked but that's because can tell them apart because they have different keys. If keys were identical (as in your example), their values would be wrongly assigned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219916/discussion-between-tao-and-kururin).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this
[image]

Put componentKey on v-container and use forceRender() after your push is done

Comment: Don't use images instead of code. You're disabling copy/pasting for your code, which considerably decreases the utility of your answer for both OP and future users with a similar problem.